# Programmatically create a folder in DotNetNuke 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I need to programmatically create a folder in DotNetNuke 6.0.1 and assign permission to it. In DNN 5 I was able to create folders but now something changes and all the modules I've created for 5 don't work in 6.

Please help me.

Comment: 6.x does include new and improved APIs that are built to work with the new FolderProvider infrastructure. However the 5.x APIs should still work. How were you creating folders in your modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new Folder Manager API in 6.

**FolderManager.AddFolder Method (FolderMappingInfo, String)**

**Parameters**

folderMapping

Type: DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FolderMappingInfo

The folder mapping to use.

folderPath

Type: System.String

The path of the new folder.

Return Value

The added folder.

Implements

IFolderManager.AddFolder(FolderMappingInfo, String)

[Code API help file](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/74383#DownloadId=288685)

Comment: Solved in this way: var filterFolderName = "Albums/" + txtAlbumName.Text;

                    var folderPath = PathUtils.Instance.FormatFolderPath(
                        PathUtils.Instance.FormatFolderPath(
                        PathUtils.Instance.StripFolderPath("").Replace("\\", "/")) + filterFolderName);

                    //Add Folder to Database
                    FolderManager.Instance.AddFolder(FolderMappingController.Instance.GetFolderMapping(8), folderPath);
                    FolderManager.Instance.Synchronize(this.PortalId);

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look at [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h4z99zb.aspx)

It's fairly straight forward.

Comment: While this would work, it's generally recommended to use the DNN Folder Manager API, which would enable the code to work with a number of different file storage options.